# WPF MVVM Parent View/ViewModel with child UserControl/ViewModel Data Binding Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have been trying to implement a WPF `UserControl` with some common functionality between a few different views without success. The `UserControl` is essentially a `ListBox` with some Previous & Next buttons and a Search filter. Previous and Next logic is easily copied and pasted, but the filtering is a pain each time, so it would be really nice to encapsulate that all into its own `UserControl` and `ViewModel`.

But I've been running into a wall to get the child `UserControl`/`ViewModel` to two way bind back to the parent VM.

This works if the child `UserControl` doesn't have its own `ViewModel`, but then I have to implement all the functionality in the code behind for that logic, which is unappealing, but not impossible.

I've boiled this down to a demo project- [MRE Project - ChildVMBindingDemo](https://github.com/AndyStagg/ChildVMBindingDemo)

I have a MainWindow, MainWindowViewModel, MyListBoxControl, and a MyListBoxControlViewModel.

The MainWindow.xaml hosts the MyListBoxControl, and forwards two bindings to DependencyProperty in the code behind of the MyListBoxControl. That code behind then forwards those values to the MyListBoxControlViewModel. This is obviously my issue- the "traffic" hits the code behind, sets the values in the child VM, and it's a one way street from there. I've tried every combination of BindingMode, UpdateSourceTrigger, NotifyOnSourceUpdated, and NotifyOnTargetUpdated that I can think of without success.

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <local:MyListBoxControl Grid.Column="0"
        MyItems="{Binding
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}, Mode=FindAncestor},
            Path=DataContext.MyItems}"
        SelectedMyItem="{Binding
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}, Mode=FindAncestor},
            Path=DataContext.SelectedMyItem}"
        />
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```cs
private readonly MainWindowViewModel _viewModel;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    this.DataContext = _viewModel;
}
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs:**

```cs
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    MyItems = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>()
    {
        new MyItem() { Name = "One" },
        new MyItem() { Name = "Two" },
        new MyItem() { Name = "Thee" },
        new MyItem() { Name = "Four" },
    };
}

private ObservableCollection<MyItem> _myItems;
public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItems
{
    get => _myItems;
    set => Set(ref _myItems, value);
}

private MyItem _selectedMyItem;
public MyItem SelectedMyItem
{
    get => _selectedMyItem;
    set
    {
        if (Set(ref _selectedMyItem, value))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Main View Model Selected Item Set: {SelectedMyItem?.Name}");
        }
    }
}
```

**MyListBoxControl.xaml:**

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox Grid.Row="0"
             ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMyItem}"
             SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}">
        
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Column="0"
                Command="{Binding PrevCommand}"
                >Prev</Button>

        <Button Grid.Column="2"
                Command="{Binding NextCommand}"
                >Next</Button>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**MyListBoxControl.xaml.cs:**

```cs
private readonly MyListBoxControlViewModel _viewModel;

public MyListBoxControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _viewModel = new MyListBoxControlViewModel();
    this.DataContext = _viewModel;
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MyItemsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MyItems", typeof(ObservableCollection<MyItem>), typeof(MyListBoxControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, MyItemsChangedCallback));

public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItems
{
    get => (ObservableCollection<MyItem>)GetValue(MyItemsProperty);
    set
    {
        SetValue(MyItemsProperty, value);
        _viewModel.MyItems = MyItems;
    }
}

private static void MyItemsChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (d is MyListBoxControl myListBoxControl)
    {
        myListBoxControl.MyItems = (ObservableCollection<MyItem>)e.NewValue;
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedMyItemProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SelectedMyItem), typeof(MyItem), typeof(MyListBoxControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, SelectedMyItemChangedCallback)
        {
            BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
            DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
        });

public MyItem SelectedMyItem
{
    get => (MyItem)GetValue(SelectedMyItemProperty);
    set
    {
        SetValue(SelectedMyItemProperty, value);
        _viewModel.SelectedMyItem = SelectedMyItem;
    }
}

private static void SelectedMyItemChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (d is MyListBoxControl myListBoxControl)
    {
        myListBoxControl.SelectedMyItem = (MyItem)e.NewValue;
    }
}
```

And finally

**MyListBoxControlViewModel.cs:**

```cs
private ObservableCollection<MyItem> _myItems;
public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItems
{
    get => _myItems;
    set => Set(ref _myItems, value);
}

private MyItem _selectedMyItem;
public MyItem SelectedMyItem
{
    get => _selectedMyItem;
    set
    {
        if (Set(ref _selectedMyItem, value))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Child View Model Selected Item Set: {SelectedMyItem?.Name}");
        }
    }
}

private int _selectedIndex;
public int SelectedIndex
{
    get => _selectedIndex;
    set => Set(ref _selectedIndex, value);
}

private ICommand _prevCommand;
public ICommand PrevCommand => _prevCommand ?? (_prevCommand = new RelayCommand((param) => Prev(), (param) => CanPrev()));
public bool CanPrev() => SelectedIndex > 0;
private void Prev()
{
    SelectedIndex--;
}

private ICommand _nextCommand;
public ICommand NextCommand => _nextCommand ?? (_nextCommand = new RelayCommand((param) => Next(), (param) => CanNext()));
public bool CanNext() => MyItems != null ? SelectedIndex < (MyItems.Count - 1) : false;
private void Next()
{
    SelectedIndex++;
}
```

There were preexisting examples similar to this in our project (with the bindings in the code behind passing the values to the child VM)- so someone else struggled with this as well, and it looks like their solution was simply, that the child control never reported back to the parent- they were output only kinda deals.

The only thing I can really think of is to use a Messenger to send the selected value back to the parent directly, or give the child VM an `Action` to call and set the new value in the code behind dependency properties- but either option just screams of odorous spaghetti, and a probably an endless setter loop/stack overflow exception.

Is there a better approach here, or is there something here that I am just missing?

Comment: "*This works if the child UserControl doesn't have its own ViewModel, but then I have to implement all the functionality in the code behind*" - this is exactly what you should do. UserControls - or any other controls - should not have private view models. They should instead have their properties bound to the object in the inherited DataContext, i.e. the view model of their parent element, like e.g. `MyItems="{Binding MyItems}"`.

Comment: Besides that, be aware that when a dependency property is set by data binding, the setter of the property is bypassed, and WPF calls SetValue directly. Hence `_viewModel.MyItems = MyItems;` in the MyItems setter in MyListBoxControl is not called.

Comment: @Clemens That really doesn't help in terms of code reduction if each parent view model has to implement the INPC properties and Commands for that UserControl.

Comment: Well, that doesn't matter. Private view models just won't work well. Which is obvious if you look at the complicated Bindings in MainWindow.xaml.

Comment: "Hence _viewModel.MyItems = MyItems; in the MyItems setter in MyListBoxControl is not called" That is actually ideal (it would avoid the setter loop) but it doesn't explain why the parent VM setter doesn't get hit

Comment: Instead of creating a UserControl with a ListBox it could also make sense to derive from ListBox and put the two Buttons into the ControlTemplate. You would not have to declare MyItems, SelectedMyItem etc.

Comment: The two buttons are just an example. I have a text box search filter along with some other components as well. However, it sounds like the only way to do this is actually going to be a customcontrol.

Comment: @Clemens "User controls should not have private view models"?  Says who?  Where is that written?  A *custom* control yes, I understand.  But a *UserControl*?  I've lost count of the number of applications I've seen in which the various displays are derived from UserControl and have their own private view-models.

Comment: A UserControl is a control like any other control. Search StackOverflow for UserControl related question where people wonder why the Bindings of their control's properties fail. There are hundreds. The whole logic in your MyListBoxControlViewModel could as well be implemented in the control's code behind, with certainly less code. You don't need all the INotifyPropertyChanged and ICommand stuff.

Comment: The UserControls with private view model that you have seen might have been different from yours, in the way that  they do not expose bindable properties and are used in scenarios where they act as stand-alone views (e.g. in navigation pages). A control that should have its properties data-bound in a parent-child context is a different thing.

Comment: Anyway, if you still feel the need for having a private view model, here is a tip: Set the DataContext of the top level element in the control's XAML (the Grid here) instead of that of the control. You could then still write a standard binding expression like `MyItems="{Binding MyItems}"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A control should never depend on an explicit or internal view model. It must depend on its own members, like public properties, alone. Then the data context can later bind to this public properties.

This will enable reusability independent from the actual `DataContext` type and eliminates redundant code (and redundant complexity) that otherwise would be necessary to delegate values to the private view model.

MVVM does not mean that each control must have its own dedicated view model. It is meant to give the *application* a structure. MVVM targets application level design and not control level design. A control must implement its UI related logic in its own view code. This can be in code-behind or spread across multiple classes. Such classes would be referenced directly (and not via data binding) as they share the same MVVM context. The MVVM context of UI logic is always *View*.
Data binding is basically a technology to decouple *View* and *View Model* (to allow the *View Model* to send data to the *View* without having to reference it - which is crucial to the MVVM pattern).
Data operations usually take place in the *View Model* (the owner of the data from the *View* perspective). *View* would only operate on data views (e.g. to filter or sort collections). But never on data directly.

See how the following example moved all *View* related logic to the control.
Your fixed and improved (in terms of design) `MyListBoxControl`, could look as follows:

**MyListBoxControl.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MyListBoxControl : UserControl
{
  public static RoutedCommand NextCommand { get; } = new RoutedUICommand("Select next MyItem", "NextCommand", typeof(MyListBoxControl));
  public static RoutedCommand PreviousCommand { get; } = new RoutedUICommand("Select previous MyItem", "PreviousCommand", typeof(MyListBoxControl));

  public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItemsSource
  {
    get => (ObservableCollection<MyItem>)GetValue(MyItemsSourceProperty);
    set => SetValue(MyItemsSourceProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty MyItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "MyItemsSource", 
    typeof(ObservableCollection<MyItem>), 
    typeof(MyListBoxControl), 
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public int SelectedMyItemIndex
  {
    get => (int)GetValue(SelectedMyItemIndexProperty);
    set => SetValue(SelectedMyItemIndexProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedMyItemIndexProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SelectedMyItemIndex", 
    typeof(int), 
    typeof(MyListBoxControl), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(int), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

  public MyItem SelectedMyItem
  {
    get => (MyItem)GetValue(SelectedMyItemProperty);
    set => SetValue(SelectedMyItemProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedMyItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SelectedMyItem", 
    typeof(MyItem), 
    typeof(MyListBoxControl), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(MyItem), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

  public MyListBoxControl()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(NextCommand, ExecuteNextCommand, CanExecuteNextCommand));
    this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(PreviousCommand, ExecutePreviousCommand, CanExecutePreviousCommand));
  }

  private void CanExecutePreviousCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    => e.CanExecute = this.MyItems?.Any() ?? false  && this.SelectedMyItemIndex > 0;

  private void ExecutePreviousCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    => this.SelectedMyItemIndex = Math.Max(this.SelectedMyItemIndex - 1, 0);

  private void CanExecuteNextCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) 
    => e.CanExecute = this.MyItems?.Any() ?? false  && this.SelectedMyItemIndex < this.MyItemsSource.Count - 1;

  private void ExecuteNextCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) 
    => this.SelectedMyItemIndex = Math.Min(this.SelectedMyItemIndex + 1, this.MyItemsSource.Count - 1);
}
```

**MyListBoxControl.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox Grid.Row="0"
             ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=MyItemsSource}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=SelectedMyItem}"
             SelectedIndex="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=SelectedMyItemIndex}">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <Button Grid.Column="0"
              Command="{x:Static local:MyListBoxControl.PreviousCommand}"
              Content="Prev" />
      <Button Grid.Column="2"
              Command="{x:Static local:MyListBoxControl.NextCommand}"
              Content="Next" />
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

### Usage example

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <MainViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <MyListBoxControl MyItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
                    SelectedMyItem="{Binding SelectedMyItem}" />
</Window>
```

In case you meant to add behavior or change the behavior of the existing `ListBox`, extending `ListBox` would be the far better option. This would allow to template its items out of the box.

Additionally, if your primary intention was to separate view and related logic, always extend `Control` i.e. don't create a `UserControl`. It will also feel more natural to implement the control without a code-behind file. It will also enable more flexibility in terms of customization. For example, although `UserControl` is a `ContentControl`, it can't host content.

Comment: Gotcha- So let the logic live in the code behind for the usercontrol, and because the datacontext for the control in that case is the VM, the bindings within the control xaml redirect back to the usercontrol itself.

Comment: Yes, internals bind to properties of the templated control or UserControl. Those properties are later bound to a view model (or whatever the data source is) or are alternatively set locally, for example `<MyListBoxControl MySelectedItemIndex="2" />`. This properties are the interface of the control (API). The internals connect to this interface and the user of the control connects this interface to a data source or provides local values. This is also exactly the way how WPF controls are designed.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to code out a complete answer. It's much appreciated.

Comment: I'm happy I could help. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score -2):

It's sure not pretty, and it doesn't smell great- but if this is your only option, here is how this could work.

I added an `Action` to the ViewModel, to set the DP in the code behind- note that it's only calling SetValue, and not directly setting the SelectedMyItem, which prevents the setter loop I was worried about.

**MyListBoxControlViewModel.cs**

```cs
public Action<MyItem> SelectedSetter { get; set; }

private MyItem _selectedMyItem;
public MyItem SelectedMyItem
{
    get => _selectedMyItem;
    set
    {
        if (Set(ref _selectedMyItem, value))
        {
            SelectedSetter?.Invoke(value);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Child View Model Selected Item Set: {SelectedMyItem?.Name}");
        }
    }
}
```

and

**MyListBoxControl.xmal.cs**

```cs
public MyListBoxControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _viewModel = new MyListBoxControlViewModel();
    _viewModel.SelectedSetter = (value) => SetValue(SelectedMyItemProperty, value);

    this.DataContext = _viewModel;
}
```

While not great, it would probably work in limited use.

Probably smart to pass the Action in via the constructor to state its importance in the operation.